# cassandra 3.4 on virtual box not starting

Tags: linux, cassandra

I am using mac osx. i created 3 virtual box by virtualbox. I've installed centos7 minimal version on each of the virtual box. 
Then i installed cassandra on each of the box. After installation it was starting by cqlsh and nodetool status command. 
But after then when i was trying to link each other and edit cassandra.yaml file its started showing

```
('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

i've edited the cassandra.yaml file as follows:

```
cluster_name: 'Home Cluster'  
num_tokens: 256   
partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner     
- seeds: "192.168.56.102,192.168.56.103"   
storage_port: 7000     
listen_address: 192.168.56.102
rpc_address: 192.168.56.102
rpc_port: 9160
endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch
```

my /etc/hosts file contains:

```
192.168.56.102 node01
192.168.56.103 node02
192.168.56.104 node03
```

Please tell me whats wrong i'm doing? My cassandra cluster not working.

solution: I got the solution from AKKI. The problem was enpoint_snitch. I made the endpoint_snitch=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch and it fixed. My now output is as follows:

```
[root@dbnode2 ~]# nodetool status
Datacenter: dc1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.56.101  107.38 KB  256          62.5%             0526a2e1-e6ce-4bb4-abeb-b9e33f72510a  rack1
UN  192.168.56.102  106.85 KB  256          73.0%             0b7b76c2-27e8-490f-8274-571d00e60c20  rack1
UN  192.168.56.103  83.1 KB    256          64.5%             6c8d80ec-adbb-4be1-b255-f7a0b63e95c2  rack1
```

Comment: Simple test. From each virtual box, on the command line, please ensure that you can ping the 2 other Cassandra using their IP (192.168.56.xxx). I suspect this is a simple network issue

Comment: Yes i can ping successfully. Everything is ok. I can SSH to every node from each other. I really want to complete the cluster . but just stucked here. unable to find any solutions.

Comment: Please post an extract of `/var/log/cassandra/system.log` to see the whole exception stack trace

Comment: Where did that log appear? It seems that you are connecting to 127.0.0.1. Although your nodes have an uo if 192.168.56.xxx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had faced similar problem, 
I tried the following solution:

In Cassandra.yaml file check if you have,

```
start_rpc = true
```

Changed my endpoint snitch to

```
endpoint_snitch: GossipingFilePropertySnitch
```

Opened all ports Cassandra uses on my CentOS

```
Cassandra inter-node ports
Port number Description
7000    Cassandra inter-node cluster communication.
7001    Cassandra SSL inter-node cluster communication.
7199    Cassandra JMX monitoring port.


Cassandra client port
Port number Description
9042    Cassandra client port.
9160    Cassandra client port (Thrift).
```

Command to open ports on CentOs 7(Find it according to your OS):

```
>sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=9042/tcp --permanent
>sudo firewall-cmd –reload
```

Then Restart your systems

Also it seems that you are changing the Cassandra.Yaml file after starting cassandra.
Make sure you edit your Cassandra.yaml file on all nodes before starting Cassandra
Also remember to start the seed node first.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear. Its working right now. Problem was endpoint_snitch: GossipingFilePropertySnitch.. Thanks a lot for solving the issues. :) :)

Comment: Hello dear, I edited my question with your solution and wrote the output. please reload the question and check the output result. It showing 62%, 73%, 64% each node owns. is it ok? i thought it should be 33,33,33% . is it correct ??

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

You can read more about it here : https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeDistribute_c.html

Comment: Dear Akki, I'm facing another problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643249/how-to-use-private-networking-at-cassandra-node-with-one-public-ip-at-seeders-no
Can you please have a look here???